# For loop in python For loop

Tags: python

In this question we have to find the subarry of the array in which aum of all elements and product of all elements are equal.
in the code for loop below the function is not giving output.

```
import math
try:
    t=int(input())
    for i in range(t):
        n=int(input())
        l1=list(map(int,input().split()))
        def ls (l):
            lists = []
            for v in range(len(l) + 1):
                for x in range(v):
                    lists.append(l[x: v])
            return lists
        k=ls(l1)
        for j in k:
            su=sum(j)
            muk=math.prod(l)
            if su==muk:
                print(j)
            else:
                pass
        
except:
    pass
```

[question](https://www.codechef.com/problems/CHEFARRP)

Comment: Please  clarify your question. Add the desired output, and a **full** working code, without a link to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
muk=math.prod(l)
```

This sould be changed to:

```
muk=math.prod(j)
```

Here I suggest a better solution with cumulative sum and multiplication with the same O(n^2) time complexity but better memory (O(n)):

```
import math

t=int(input())
for i in range(t):
    n = int(input())
    l = list(map(int,input().split()))
    sums = [0]
    prods = [1]
    for x in l:
        sums.append(sums[-1] + x)
        prods.append(prods[-1] * x)
    for i in range(len(sums)):
        for j in range(i):
            if sums[i] - sums[j] == prods[i] // prods[j]:
                print(j+1, i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting a `try/except` around everything means that if there's an exception you won't get any output, so remove that for easier debugging.  (Catching an exception and just doing `pass` is almost never the right thing to do!)  Just doing that and running the code gets us this error:

```
NameError: name 'l' is not defined
```

which is happening because you got confused with all the different variables in the main function and the helper function.  You don't need the helper function at all IMO, just iterate through the indices and use the slice operator:

```
import math

for _ in range(int(input())):
    n = int(input())
    a = list(map(int, input().split()))
    assert len(a) == n
    print(sum(
        math.prod(a[i:j]) == sum(a[i:j])
        for i in range(n)
        for j in range(i+1, n+1)
    ))
```